# Changes to Clip and Intersect between 2.8 ltr and 2.12 for lines

Tags: clip, google-earth

Clip and Intersect in 2.8 yield the result as expected. When using 2.12 the shapefile is empty.

To test this I have run both versions on Linux (Opensuse Leap) and OSX. The results are consistent.

Workflow:

1. Create a polygon in Google Earth (a dam outline) and save as a KML file
2. Set the project CRS to HBK lo 31 (South African projected coordinate system with CM 31)
3. Add a vector layer using the KML polygon
4. Save the polygon to a Shapefile using CRS HBK Lo 31
5. Disable the KML layer
6. Add a Vector Grid. Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector Grid
7. Save using CRS HBK Lo 31
8. Clip the lines to the polygon. Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Clip

In 2.8 this works fine. In 2.12 it returns an empty file.

If I use points the clip works fine (Vector -> Research Tools -> Regular Points) in both versions.

The only reason I wish to use 2.12 is that it allows for a rotation of the grid.

Has something changed that I need to modify the workflow?